# Is there a way to show a stack trace when Entity Framework logging has been enabled?

Tags: c#, logging, entity-framework-6

I have configured `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` to see what SQL queries are being executed by Entity Framework on .NET Core 2.1.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    {
         loggingBuilder.AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Information);
         loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
    });

    services.AddDbContext<dbContext>(options => 
         options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContext")));
}
```

From this I receive warnings that client side evaluation is being performed and also SQL scripts that Entity Framework generates. This works well but it is not that clear how to generate a link back to the linq / lambda code where the SQL was generated in the logs. I would expect to be able to trace back to the point at which the EF datasets were instantiated.

Can this be done with `LoggerInterceptors`?

Comment: If you upgrade your EF you'll start getting client-side eval exceptions instead ;)

Comment: The answer above applies to 2.1 as well. I have added the following code ```services.AddDbContext<AuditContext>(options =>              options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()                     .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContext"))                    .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning)));```. This creates the stack trace I am after.

Comment: If it answers the question, I definitely recommend posting it as an answer; i'll pick up upvotes and not run as much risk of deletion (comments are ephemeral by definition)

Comment: Looks like RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning is now deprecated. Is there any other way I can get the stack trace.